# Custom Twitter Widget - Limit the number of tweets

Tags: json, widget, twitter

I followed this tutorial to create a custom twitter widget. 
It basically uses the Twitter API, Json to pull tweets.

http://www.evoluted.net/thinktank/web-development/creating-your-own-twitter-trends-widget

As in the tutorial I have got the tweets.
But I would like to limit the number of tweets which appear to maybe 2.

Site - http://testingweddev.comli.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `rpp=` parameter to the url

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // json call to twitter to request tweets containing our keyword, in this case 'sheffield'
  $.getJSON("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=sheffield&rpp=2&callback=?", function(data) {
    // loop around the result
    $.each(data.results, function() {
      var text = this.text;

      if(text.charAt(0) != '@') {
        // construct tweet and add append to our #tweets div
        var tweet = $("<div></div>").addClass('tweet').html(text);
        // analyse our tweet text and turn urls into working links, hash tags into search links, and @replies into profile links.
        tweet.html('<div class="content">' + 
          tweet.html()
          .replace(/((ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?)/gi,'<a href="$1">$1</a>')
          .replace(/(^|\s)#(\w+)/g,'$1<a href="http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23$2">#$2</a>')
          .replace(/(^|\s)@(\w+)/g,'$1<a href="http://twitter.com/$2">@$2</a>')
          + '<br /><a href="http://www.twitter.com/' + this.from_user + '/status/' + this.id_str + '" class="view" target="_blank">' + $.timeSinceTweet(this.created_at) + '</a></div>'
          )
          .prepend('<a href="http://www.twitter.com/' + this.from_user + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + this.profile_image_url + '" width="48" height="48" /></a>')
          .appendTo('#tweets')
          .fadeIn();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And don't forget to switch to API 1.1. [See API 1.1 search documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets). API 1.1 uses the count param to specify the tweets limit.

Comment: Also it displays tweets only which are recently posted. Any way to display tweets which are previously posted?.

Comment: See the search documentation on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search. Check out the result_type option for the different types of tweets.